# Expected values in mixed strategies

Tags: expected-value, game-theory, nash-equilibrium

If we have two actions $a_1$ and $a_2$ that in an equilibrium mixed strategy should be mixed $70\%/30\%$ with both having an expected value of say $10$. What happens to the expected values of the actions if we $100\%$ of the time do action $a_1$?

My thinking was that the expected value of the action we always do $a_1$ will go down?

Edit: Practical example. In a hand of poker, we calculate the optimal strategy, which is a mixed strategy between betting our hand for size $A$ $70\%$ of the time and size $B$ $30\%$ of the time. The expected value of these two bets is equal since it is a mixed strategy. My question then is by deviating from this optimal strategy, what would happen to the expected values. My intuition was that if we start betting our hand for size $A$ $100\%$ of the time instead of $70\%$, then the expected value of this action would go down? But maybe it stays the same, that's what I'm asking.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Remember that expectation is a linear operator, so if you have $\mathbb{E}[X]$ and $\mathbb{E}[Y]$ then
$$
\mathbb{E}[aX + bY] = a\mathbb{E}[X] + b \mathbb{E}[Y]
$$ for any constants $a,b$.

Comment: But anyway, there's something I don't quite understand about your question. You say that both actions have the same expected value, equal to 10. So do you mean that
$$
\mathbb{E}[A_1] = 10 \qquad \text{and} \qquad \mathbb{E}[A_2] = 10
$$
or 
$$
\mathbb{E}[0.7A_1 + 0.3 A_2] = 10
$$
?

Comment: Yes i mean since in mixed strategies all actions have the same expected value but should be performed different amount of the times

Comment: If you have different random variables with the same expected value (10), then a linear combinations of those (so that the factors add to 1) also has an expected value of 10. That's due to the linear nature of expected value.

Comment: Ok, so doing action a1 100% instead of 70% of the time as suggested by the equilibrium it will still have an expected value of 10?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  What do you mean when you say "both have an expected value of $10$"?  Against which strategy?  If, say, you mean the expectation is independent of the strategy either player chooses, then what would be the point of any particular mixed strategy?  Any other mix would have the same expectation.

Comment: I would interpret that as so. So the main takeaway is: How you use the outcome of a random variable, doesn't change its properties (before the "use case").

Comment: Please edit your post for clarity.  As you can see from the comments, people are not at all sure what you are assuming or what you are asking.

Comment: All I'm asking is we have calculated a mixed strategy, against which strategy doesn't matter, just that the equilibrium strategy is to do a1 70% of the time and a2 30% of the time. If we decide to despite this equilibrium strategy do a1 100% of the time, would our strategy of only doing a1 100% of the time yield a lower expected value than 10? As it would with the equilibrium strategy. Since in a mixed strategy all actions have equal expected value.

Comment: Please edit your post to clarify your question.  If I understand your question (which I doubt) then the answer is clearly "it depends on the situation."  If the game is independent of strategy then it makes no difference what you do.  On the other hand, there are strategy dependent games for which the mixed strategy is strictly optimal.

Comment: Should add:  it would be somewhat unusual to speak of a mixed equilibrium strategy in a strategy-independent  game (what would be the point, after all?)  so if you are looking for someone to guess then I'd guess that the discussion here concerns a game for which the mixed equilibrium is strictly optimal.

Comment: Ok i will try to give you a practical example.

In a hand of poker, we calculate the optimal strategy, which is a mixed strategy between betting our hand for size A 70% of the time and size B 30% of the time. The expected value of these two bets are equal since it is a mixed strategy. My question then is by deviating from this optimal strategy, what would happen to the expected values. 

My intuition was that if we start betting our hand for size A 100% of the time instead of 70%, then the expected value of this action would go down? But maybe it stays the same, that's what I'm asking.

Comment: Yes a mixed strategy would be strictly optimal in this game

Comment: Please edit your post for clarity.  Do not leave critical information in the comments (which can not be searched and which are frequently deleted).

Comment: But, just to say:  "strictly optimal" means "better than all other strategies" so, by definition, any other strategy has a lower expectation.

Comment: Ok good, thats what i was thinking

Answer (score 1):

If you mix actions, it means that you are indifferent between them so, given the other player does not change his strategy, you might as well play just one of them $100\%$ of the time and get the same payoff. However, if the other player responds, then there might be multiple scenarios and it also depends whether you consider a new equilibrium or just the payoff of the new strategy profile.

For example, in the "matching pennies" game, if you play pure then the other player best responds and your payoff is lower. But in such a game, there is no pure NE, and you can best respond to his best response and so on.

On the other hand, in a game such as "Battle of the Sexes", if you play purely and the other player best responds, you both arrive at one of the pure equilibria of the game, where the payoff is strictly higher than the mixed one.